# Router can't handle my ISP's download bandwidth over LAN, how do I find a replacement that can?

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth

I have a router (ASUS RT-N16; QoS is off) that is running Tomato. With my router, I get roughly 120 Mbps in speed tests.

However, when connected directly to the modem (without any router), I can get around 180Mbps (my current plan is 150Mbps).

How do I go about picking a router with a CPU/hardware that I can be confident will be able to handle this higher speed?

Aside from just picking an expensive router blindly, what technical specification of a router can help determine what speeds the CPU will be able to handle? Does simply looking at clock speed give a good sense? My current clock speed is 480MHz.

It doesn't seem like any router lists these kinds of details.

To be clear, my question has nothing to do with WIFI. Just noting that because so many Google'd questions are about WIFI.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is no other devices connected to your router (wifi or wired) when you do your test?  Since you installed Tomato, it may be easy to assume that the issue could also come from other options/configurations that you set on it.  Had you done a speed test with the original firmware before blaming the hardware?

Comment: I don’t quite get the situation. You have a fast router, but don’t want to use it? Instead, you use an ASUS router? Why?

Comment: @DanielB, the 180 Mbps comes when he is connected directly to the modem, without a router.  When adding the router into the mix, the speeds are reduced.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am certain. I disabled DHCP and looked at the connected device list, unplugged all other ethernet cords except my computer, rebooted, and ran my tests. No, I did not do a speed test on the original firmware.

Comment: At this point you may have to disable all enabled options to see if it makes a difference, mainly the firewall.

Comment: You may want to take a look at EdgeOS or Microtik routers. Each claims to be the fastest available, but both require knowledge of Linux for a proper setup. They are **professionally** pliable.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It’s not really a hardware shopping question. He’s asking how to infer a router’s actual performance from its specifications. That’s actually a very good question.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like that of course isn’t listed in the specs. It wouldn’t be very good advertising if the manufacturer admitted its “Gigabit Router” could only actually route 200 Mbps.

Then, there’s hardware acceleration: Most routers’ CPUs are just way to slow to handle the traffic. That’s why some sort of hardware acceleration is usually used to speed things up. Most third-party firmware (like OpenWRT, Tomato, ...) is *not* able to use this acceleration. Instead, they rely solely on the CPU.

What you need to do is the same as with any other thing you’re looking to buy: read reviews! A relatively well-known source of (IMHO) reliable information is [SmallNetBuilder](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/).

**tl;dr**: Read reviews, specs suck.

Decent routers are usually ~100 € in Europe, probably a little more on the US. Premium models may offer more features, but most likely no improvement in performance.